# flushing datacache on linux

Tags: linux, caching

What is the standard way to manipulate the data-cache on linux from a user-mode program?

I'd like to writeback and invalidate the data-cache of a memory region that that is shared between my user-mode program and a peripheral device.

Linux has no driver for it, and writing one myself would be overkill for the simple things I want to do...

Answer (score 1):

How do you share the memory region without a driver?

But anyway, look at the `msync` functions.

Comment: by using mmap on /dev/mem... dirty but it works.. :-) Thanks for the hint.. I'll take a look.